# How do I get the return value of a Powershell script that is run in Excel VBA?

Tags: powershell, excel, return-value, vba

I am using Excel VBA to run a simple Powershell script that, when run in Powershell itself, returns one or two file names of some files within a given directory.

I can run this script from my VBA, but the return value is always some random integer. How do I get the script to return the file names that were returned through the Powershell script?

VBA to call script:

```
 Dim weekly As String

 weekly = Shell("Powershell ""<location of powershell script.ps1>"" ")
```

Script:

```
Get-ChildItem "<directory to search in>" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "<regex to find file name>"}
```

If I have missed any details, please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is way late but I wanted to let anyone else searching for this a way to do this.
Have your powershell script write an output file:

```
Get-ChildItem "Directory to Search" | Select-String -Pattern "what to seach for" | out-file "C:\output.txt"
```

From there you can write this line by line to a variable:

```vb
Sub test()
Dim txtfile, text, textline As String

txtfile = "C:\output.txt"

Open txtfile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    text = text & textline
Loop

Close #1

MsgBox text

End Sub
```

From there you can insert the text into a cell, or if preferred, you can write each line to an array and select each line individually if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the VBA is simply seeing the exit code that the powershell.exe quits with.  Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem "<directory to search in>" | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "<regex to find file name>"} 2>&1
```

I believe this will redirect your Powershell output to stdout which the VBA should be able to pick up.

Comment: I was so excited for this to work! It didn't, however. Do you think there may be another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WScript to access StdOut output of a PowerShell script. Use the following code:

```
Set wShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set wShellOutput = wShell.Exec("powershell 'C:\Path\To\file.ps1'")
text_output = wShellOutput.StdOut.ReadAll ()
```

I would suggest using single quotes instead of double quotes in the .Exec() call, because Windows handles double quotes painfully.